# Weird Office 2016 Issues

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I currently have about 6 people with an odd office issue. When in word or excel and they try to select a font it comes up and then flashes and goes away or if there in a cell and try to right click comes and then flashes and goes away.

I have unistalled and reinstalled ran updates checked keyboard mouse drivers. Safe mode etc still no luck

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: Does it happen with all fonts?  Is it happening on different PCs (you mentioned 6 people, but let's also clarify that it's separate PCs)?  Is this office 2016 standalone or Office 365?  Has anyone made any changes to the default template file C:\Users\user name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm ?  Does it let you write or fill cells in the default font?  Can you take a Youtube of the issue as it happens?

Comment: Happens when trying to pick a font from the list you click the dropdown and boom it goes away. Office 2016 Standalone . Not that I know of. Sure Ill make a video...

Comment: Here is the video https://youtu.be/yzuLesWUi3k

Comment: I created a new user profile on one of the machines and no more issue. But thats not really a fix